# How to change a color of single cell in spark DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid

let's say I have rowIndex and columnIndex and I want to change background color of this cell

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is by extending the default itemRenderer and overriding the set data method:

```
 override public function set data(value:Object):void {
            super.data = value;
            // retrieve the value of the list-based control's new public property
            var minAge:Number = (listData.owner as MyList).minAge;
            if (data.age < minAge) {
                listLabel.setStyle("color",0xFF0000);
            } else {
                listLabel.setStyle("color",0x000000);
            }
        }
```

Here is a link to a good example :

http://blog.flexdevelopers.com/2009/06/flex-examples-item-renderers-in.html